# Create Highchart Graph with Dynamic Data

Tags: dynamic, highcharts, axis

I want to create the following:

1. I want to have a database of more than 100 X-Axis categories (e.g. 100+, these are products)
2. I want the HighChart to display product X in the centre of the chart with 2 closes X-axis values above and 2 lowest x-axis values below.(so total 5 x-axis values)
3. If I update the database, I want the charts to automatically adjust and looking for the closest X-axis values below and up.

Can anyone help me how I can realise this?

Comment: you can show 2 labels , one for lowest and other for highest value. use min and max under x axis to do so. from your array of xAxis categories pic    value at 0 index as min and array.length-1 index as max value

Comment: There are a lot of topics there.  You need to come up with something more specific to ask...

Comment: 1) You can create array of 100+ categories, could you elaborate what kind of problem you have with that point?

2) Any mockup of that? 

3) You can use a sockets or call ajax each time (like 1s) and check if something is different in database. You need setup for example PHP script, which gets data from database and return that as JSON.

Comment: The first point was not a question, sorry for that. 2) I know how to create chart with 100+ categories. But I want to show only 5 of them. I don't want to create a new chart every time. e.g. I have a chart with 100 categories ranging from 1 - 100. I want to select category 35, and that it automaticallys only shows (33-34-35-36-37). So i do not have to create 100 unique charts.

Comment: You can use [setCategories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setCategories) to manipulate xAxis labesl.